# How to show added product details after clicked shopping cart icon in angular 8

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I tried to show added product details after i clicked shopping cart icon or if i added any one product same like https://designmodo.com/shopping-cart-ui/. Initially no need to show the" Your Cart Items" added product box.I do not know how to do like that.If any one know please help to find the solutions.

addtocart-dir.ts:

```
 <div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    Your Cart Items
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right">
        Total items <span class="badge badge-light">{{cart.cartItemsList.length}}</span>        
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger mr-2 float-right" (click)="emptyCart()" *ngIf="cart.cartItemsList && cart.cartTotal">
       Empty Cart       
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">  
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>      
          <th scope="col">Product</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Qty</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let itm of cart.cartItemsList ">      
          <td class="text-left">{{itm.name}}</td>
          <td>{{itm.price/itm.qty}} x</td>
          <td class="w30">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" (click)="changeQty(itm.pid,1,'')">+</button>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="{{itm.qty}}" #qtyRef (keyup)="changeQty(itm.pid,qtyRef.value,'replace')" >
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="changeQty(itm.pid,-1,'')">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>{{itm.price}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a routerLink = "/billing" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" *ngIf="cart.cartItemsList && cart.cartTotal">Checkout</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted font-weight-bold">
    Total : Rs. {{cart.cartTotal}}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-btjqde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Faddtocart.dir.ts

Answer (score 0):

1. Change in cart.service.ts

   ```
   public cartItemsList: any  = [];
   ```
2. change in products.pages.ts

   ```
   <div class="row">
      <div [ngClass]="cart.cartItemsList.length == 0 ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-7'">  
      <productslist-dir (refresh)="ref($event)" [allProductList]="products.data [searchedText]="searchText" [sortingBy]="sortOption"></productslist-dir>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5" *ngIf="cart.cartItemsList.length > 0">
        <cart></cart>
     </div>
   ```
3. change in productslist.dir.ts

   ```
   ngOnInit(){
    this.sortByOption = 'product_name';    
    this.cart.allItems = this.__allprdts;
    this.cart.storeItems();
   }

   addToCart(productId,productQty){
     this.cart.addToCart(productId,productQty,'');
     this.refresh.emit(true);
   }
   ```

please check and let me know..

Comment: Thanks..I want to show below shopping cart icon like tooltip..after clicked cornar shopping cart icon or after added any one product..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-aquv2q?file=src/app/pages/products/products.pages.ts

Comment: check these websites:https://designmodo.com/shopping-cart-ui/

Comment: click  cornar cart icon..popup or tooltip will come

Comment: check this example also:http://lab.iamrohit.in/demos/?t=%20%20Shopping%20Cart%20Dropdown%20%20%20&d=%20Based%20on%20this%20dribbble%20shot%20%20http%20%20%20drbl%20in%20prBM%20%20%20%20&u=https://codepen.io/drehimself/pen/VvYLmV

Comment: please refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/mu5mvba0/

Comment: I do not know how to use it in angular..please update my stackblitz using this style:http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/mu5mvba0/